# BIng Maps not rendering migrated polygons

Tags: path, maps, polygon, bing-maps, bing

I have a map, that has both new and migrated areas. The new areas are being pushed to the map, but the migrated ones are not. They are somewhat loading, as the length of the collection is correct. map.entites.push('polygon') is not working.

here is the code I am using:

```
var checkExist = setInterval(function () {

        var counter = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < viewData.zones.length; i++) {

            var zone = viewData.zones[i];
            var id = zone["ID"];
            var geometricArea = zone["CoverageArea"];
            var geography = geometricArea["Geography"];
            //console.log("geography object :" + JSON.parse(geography));

            //var zoneShape = zoneShapes[i];
            // console.log(geography.WellKnownText);
            var polygon = WKTModule.Read(geography.WellKnownText)
            polygon.shapeType = ('Polygon').toLowerCase();

            polygon.id = id;

            map.entities.push(polygon);
            zoneEntities.push(polygon);
    });

});
```

Also- Even though the polygon isnt being pushed to the map, the coordinates are there and it has an id. I am not sure what is happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is the zoneEntities variable? If it is a layer/entityCollection this would cause an issue as you already tried adding the shape to the map. Which map control are you using V7 or v8. V8 renders on an HTML5 canvas and has to redraw with every change to your shape. If you are changing the shapes in an interval like this and the interval is too small, the renderer will wait for the changes to stop for a period of time before drawing. Looking at your code you aren't specifying an interval time which means it is firing this even a ridiculous number of times.